# How to know the initiator of the javascript clipboard "copy" event

Tags: javascript, clipboard, clipboarddata

I've registered a listener for the Clipboard copy event in the content script as follows:

```
document.addEventListener("copy", function(event){
    console.log("Copy event received");
});
```

I get the event in the following cases:

1. 'Ctrl+C' from keyboard.
2. 'Copy' selected from the right click context menu.
3. 'Copy' selected from the toolbar menu

   [image: Toolbar copy]

In all the above 3 cases, I get the "copy" event but I do not know from where the copy was initiated.

Is there a way to know the source from where the copy was initiated ? Eg: 'keyboard', 'context_menu', 'toolbar' ?

Comment: `console.log(event);` log the event and try to find the difference after initiating it by all 3 ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you need listeners for the events you want to monitor. Something like:

```js
let fromCtrlC = false;
let fromRightClick = false;
document.addEventListener( "copy", evt => {
  console.clear();
  const originatorEvent = fromCtrlC ? "CTRL-C" :
    fromRightClick ? "right click" : "toolbar menu"
  console.log(`Copy event received from ${originatorEvent} within element`, 
    evt.target);
  fromCtrlC = false;
  fromRightClick = false;
});
document.addEventListener( "keydown", evt => 
  fromCtrlC = evt.key.toUpperCase() == 'C' && evt.ctrlKey );
document.addEventListener( "contextmenu", evt => fromRightClick = true );
```

```html
<div id="hi">Hello</div>
<div id="world">world</div>
<div id="lorem">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed 
do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi 
ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore 
eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat 
non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
</div>
```